# Zsh on startup doesn't load

Tags: mac, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm having some issues with my terminal loading. I am using zsh + oh-my-zsh and seem to be having 2 seperate issues with them.

1. The `oh-my-zsh.sh` file seems to take 43 seconds to load, which in turn means the `.zshrc` file also takes a long time (about 49 seconds). I am calculating this using the following in both files which gives me the [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IPuj.png) timings

```
start=`date +%s`

[file_contents]

end=`date +%s`

runtime=$((end-start))
```

2. Once the files do completely load the terminal doesn't go to the prompt but seems to just hang. I'm not sure if this is because another file is running afterwards which is causing it to hang or something but this happens in both iterm and the default terminal application.

If someone could help, that would be very appreciated, especially with problem 2. I can probably eventually work through the long load times in problem 1 but don't even know where to start with problem 2.

If it helps, this is my `.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export ZSH="/Users/Sohaib.Ashraf@ibm.com/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true

plugins=(
brew
cp
git 
history-substring-search
osx
poetry
zsh-autosuggestions zsh-completions zsh-syntax-highlighting
)

autoload -U compinit && compinit

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

complete -F __start_kubectl k

source /usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
source <(kubectl completion zsh)
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOROOT="$(brew --prefix golang)/libexec"
export PATH="$PATH:${GOPATH}/bin:${GOROOT}/bin"

export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"

timezsh() {
  shell=${1-$SHELL}
  for i in $(seq 1 5); do /usr/bin/time $shell -i -c exit; done
}

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/yq@3/bin:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/yq@3/bin:$PATH"

[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
```

Thanks!

Comment: The lag time is likely due to one or more of the enabled plugins or the theme - when commenting out `plugins=( ... )`, does the lag still occur? What about when changing themes?

Comment: @sohaib It would really if you could trim down your `.zshrc` file to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @JW0914 - it looks like you were right. It seems that the theme, powerlevel10k, is the one causing an issue. Not sure why this is happening now as it seemed to work fine previously.

Comment: @MarlonRichert I've changed the `zshrc` file to show that it seems to just be the theme that is the problem.

Comment: @sohaib `powerlevel<#>k` are heavily customized themes, but it's unlikely the entire theme is causing the lag - you may want to check out its theme file(s) and start backtracing from there, disabling certain parts of the theme until you find the cause. _(What Marlon meant was to remove comment lines and lines containing benign code [`alias`, `echo`, etc.] - [example](https://pastebin.com/g2DuL7Fp))_

Comment: @sohaib Is that really your _entire_ `.zshrc` file? Because `source ~/.p10k.zsh` alone is not enough to fully initialize P10k. You also need to `source /path/to/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme`.

Comment: Ah, apologies about that - fixed with the correct zshrc file. Those lines are the only ones that reference powerlevel10k in my zshrc file. I am also using oh-my-zsh which handled the installation for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up just reinstalling `powerlevel10k` and that seems to have fixed the ridiculously long load times, though it still takes a couple of seconds.

Thanks for the help in the comments, much appreciated the time and effort